# What is the function of unit test in jira software

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, create-react-app, babel-loader

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlKZs.jpg)

While working on the team project, I saw that cumin software has an option called unit testing. I want to know how to work with this option.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a generic definition of unit tests, the meaning of which is common across the software engineering field.

Unit tests are used to verify individual pieces of code like functions. For example - testing that your sort function actually sorts an array properly by giving it some sample inputs and checking the outputs automatically.

This is in contrast to integration tests, which are used to test the entire application as a whole. For example, testing your UI to see if it handles user interactions correctly.